# how do you call a value entered in a UI to your java class?

Tags: java, android, math

Making a simple app for my android.

in my xml interface there is a text box in which the user will input a number (for example: 10). the id of this text box is "input1"

how do I call the value of input1 in java and then perform a calculation on it?

For example...

suppose input1 = x

x + 5   or  x*2

and for that matter, how do I have the resulting value appear as constantly updated text output in a specified place on the UI?

Comment: This is a duplicate of your earlier question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123993/converting-equations-to-java-for-android

Also, perhaps you should try reading some of the beginner Android tutorials and getting a beginner Java book or something.  These questions are so basic I can't believe you've tried learning how to do any of this on your own.

Answer (score 4):

In the `Activity` where you are using this layout XML, you would do this:

```
private EditText input;
private EditText result;

public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
    setContentView(R.layout.my_activity);

    // Extract the text fields from the XML layout
    input = (EditText) findById(R.id.input1);
    result = (EditText) findById(R.id.result);

    // Perform calculation when input text changes
    input.addKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keycode, KeyEvent keyevent) {
            if (keyevent.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                doCalculation();
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}

private void doCalculation() {
    // Get entered input value
    String strValue = input.getText().toString;

    // Perform a hard-coded calculation
    int result = Integer.parseInt(strValue) * 2;

    // Update the UI with the result
    result.setText("Result: "+ result);
}
```

Note that the above includes no error handling: it assumes that you have restricted the `input1` text field to allow the input of integer numbers only.

Comment: I have a vague feeling there's a better way to determine text changes (such as when the user leaves the text field), but I haven't used it and couldn't see anything obvious in the API docs.

Answer (score 3):

In your XML you can also set `android:inputType="number"` to only allow numbers as entries.